# Default sort in Sonata Admin - Mediabundle

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

When I use the Sonata Mediabundle, the latest images which were uploaded come up on the 80th something page, therefore I thought it can be easier to create a new extended bundle, which changes the order of the sort using the updated time :

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin as SonataAdmin;

/**
 * Class ClientAdmin
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Admin
 */
class ClientAdmin extends SonataAdmin
{

    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @param string $class
     * @param string $baseControllerName
     */
    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
        $this->datagridValues = array(
            '_page' => 1,
            '_sort_order' => 'DESC',
            '_sort_by' => 'updatedAt',
        );
    }
}
```

The service looks like this:

```
services:
  application_sonata_admin.admin.client_admin:
      class: Application\Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\ClientAdmin
      tags:
          - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: "Clients"}
      arguments:
          - ~
          - '%sonata.classification.admin.collection.entity%'
          - '%sonata.classification.admin.collection.controller%'
```

When I directly modified the datagridvalues in the admin bundle, the sort worked well ( DESC by updatedAt), what did I do wrongly with the extend?
I followed [this instruction](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html).

UPDATE: As a helpful comment below, I removed the extension of the main admin, and tried to extend the BaseMedia, but the order is still wrong.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin;

/**
 * Class MediaAdmin
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Admin
 */
class MediaAdmin extends BaseMediaAdmin
{
    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @param string $class
     * @param string $baseControllerName
     */
    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, $pool)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, $pool);

        $this->datagridValues = array(
            '_page' => 1,
            '_sort_order' => 'DESC',
            '_sort_by' => 'createdAt',
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the services.yml, I needed to add the following line:

```
 parameters:
    sonata.media.admin.media.class: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin
```

Also I extended wrong class, what I needed to extend was the  Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\PHPCR\MediaAdmin class instead of the Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\PHPCR\MediaAdmin as BaseMediaAdmin;

/**
 * Class MediaAdmin
 *
 * @package Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin
 */
class MediaAdmin extends BaseMediaAdmin
{
    protected $datagridValues = array(
        '_page' => 1,
        '_per_page' => 25,
        '_sort_order' => 'DESC',
        '_sort_by' => 'createdAt',
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created a new Admin, instead of overriding an existing one.

Make sure you extend the MediaBundle (not AdminBundle), add a new class called: `Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin` and use the constructor you've already written.

You shouldn't need to add any service declaration for your use-case.

Comment: The parent in my mediabundle is CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle. I removed the service declaration ( as well the original SonataAdmin extension) .

Comment: After a  debug, If I extend BaseMediaAdmin , that code doesn't run. Any ideas why?